# Python Tasks in MWAA Airflow are failing

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow-2.x, mwaa, airflow-webserver

I have a mwaa airflow environment that is running. I have setup the logs. All the logs seem to run in cloud watch except for dag tasks.

When I create a simple pythonoperator dag script (a function that prints hello world) the tasks fails and does not show any task log. When I create a dummy operator dag it passes but there is no log.

I have a policy like below that allows logs for cloud stream.

```
"Action": [

        "logs:CreateLogStream",

        "logs:CreateLogGroup",

        "logs:PutLogEvents",

        "logs:GetLogEvents",

        "logs:GetLogRecord",

        "logs:GetLogGroupFields",

        "logs:GetQueryResults"

    ],

    "Resource": [

        "arn:aws:logs:{your-region}:{your-account-id}:log-group:airflow-{your-environment-name}-*"

    ]

}
```

I have followed the aws troubleshooting but still cannot figure it out.